# Bash: execute when job in background completes

Tags: bash, shell

If you want to run a  series of commands, one after the other, you can execute

```
command1 & command2 & command3 &
```

If I execute `command1`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and then `bg`, it will run `command1` in the background.

My quesiton is, if I execute `command1` and send it to the background, is it possible to tell bash to wait for it to complete, then execute `command2` and `command3` in the background after it terminates?

Comment: If you need to wait until it's done, why are you putting it in the background?

Comment: Just to make it clear, you write "[i]f you want to runa _series_ of commands", while your example code `command1 & command2 & command3 &` will run all the commands in _parallel_ in the background.  However, if you want to run them _serially_, then you should use `&&` instead of `&`, as in `command1 && command2 && command3`.

Comment: `sleep 1 && echo "1" && sleep 1 && echo "2" &` will execute *sleep, echo, sleep, echo* in series, leaving you with the prompt available while doing so. As the "1" and "2" prints, they will show up at the cursor, but not be included in anything you typed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `wait`, without further specifications, **will *wait* for the end of the all the active child processes**. It means if there were another process too it will wait the end of the last that will finish.

**Wait can be called specifying an ID**: with ID is possible to pass or the **PID** (process ID) or the **job specification**. Moreover, if it was not a single command but a pipe, `wait` will wait the end of the full pipeline (See below).

So with `wait 7165` it will wait the end of the process with ID 7165, with `wait %2` of the job `[2]`.

In a script you can store the PID of the last job sent using the variable `$!`; you need to store that value because it will be updated after each command execution.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
command1 &                             # Another command in background  job [1]
command2 && command2b && command2c &   # The command in background      job [2]
PID_CMD1=$!                            # Store the PID of the last job, job [2]

some_other_commands       # ...       

                          # With this command you will 
wait                      # block all until command0 and all  
                          # the pipe of command1 are completed or...

wait $PID_CMD1            # With this command you will wait only the end
                          # of command1 pipeline or...

wait %2                   # With this command you'll wait the end of job [2]    
                          # Note that if the command 1 fails or is really fast 
                          # you can have for the command 2 the job ID 1
command3 &                # job [1] again! it's possible to recycle the numbers
command4 &                # job [2]
```

---

From `man bash`:

> The shell associates a **job** with each pipeline.  It keeps a table of currently executing jobs, which may be listed with the jobs command.  When bash starts a job asynchronously (in the background), it prints a line that looks like:
>    `[1] 25647`
>    indicating  that  this  job  is job number 1 and that the process ID of the last process in the pipeline associated with this job is 25647.  All of the processes in a single pipeline are members of the same job.  Bash uses the job abstraction as the basis for job control...

You can read more about wait with `help wait`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to do something else after starting `command1`, but before waiting for it to complete, use the shell builtin `wait`.

```
command1 &
some_other_command
wait  # block until command1 completes

command2 &
command3 &
```